# I am receiving an Application-defined or Object-defined Error?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I Keep getting the error at my if statement, I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong, any help with this would be much appreciated.

```
lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr

     DynamicLR = Sheets("RA Inventory").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    'If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumeric(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i), Sheets("RA Inventory").Range("D2:D" & DynamicLR), 0)) = False Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i), Sheets("RA Inventory").Range("D:D").Select, 0)), False) = False Then

         ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Select
         Selection.Copy
         Worksheets("RA Inventory").Activate
         ActiveSheet.Range("A" & DynamicLR).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Thanks

Comment: Which one? The commented (inactive) one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the uncommented `if` - you don't need to select and you can use syntactic sugar:

```
If [iferror(isnumber(match(A1,B:B,0)),false)] = True Then
     MsgBox ("True")
     Else: MsgBox ("False")
end if
```

Just treat the ranges as you would with functions e.g. `Sheet1!B:B`

You could also leave out the `worksheetfunction` which will allow for errors (if your formula returns an error)

```
With Application
   if .iferror(.isnumber(.match( ... 
end with
```

Essentially, your 'match' isn't referencing the data correctly. Error 2015 - see [this documentation](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/615916-catching-error-visual-basic-applications-match-function.html)

---

A larger issue might be *how* you're going about this. You should use error handling to handle the error. This would be better -

```
Sub test()
lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr

    x = Application.Match(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B" & lr), 0)
    If IsNumeric(x) Then
         MsgBox (x)
    End If
Next


End Sub
```